# Who is this character from The Neighbourhood of Make-Believe?

Tags: character-identification

My workplace has a Mr Rogers theme. On one wall are a bunch of puppets which are ostensibly ones used during the show. I can recognize all of them except for this one, which looks kind of like a jester. My only suspicion is that it might be an early prototype for Lady Elaine. Unfortunately the person who commissioned this particular design is no longer available to ask questions.

[image: Jester (?) Puppet]

Comment: https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/283130175414_/LOT-Of-4-Vintage-Mr-Rogers-Neighborhood-Land.jpg / https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-mr-rogers-neighborhood-land-468465641

Comment: Looks like [Punch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_and_Judy).

Comment: You are right. I couldn't get my image search to resolve.

Comment: Can I work there?

Comment: @mattGutting: Google Pittsburgh. We're always looking for people. :)

Comment: I don't think there is any evidence that this character (Mr Punch) actually appeared on Mr Rogers Neighborhood - just evidence that some unnamed designer *thought* that Mr Punch fit in with that theme, or that the designer mistakenly thought Mr Punch was Lady Elaine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about the Land of Make-Believe, but about a mistaken belief that a certain character belonged in the Land of Make-Believe.

Comment: @MarkBeadle - If you look at the pics I've posted above, you'll see that this puppet has appeared in at least one other set of Mr Rogers-Themed puppets

Comment: @Valorum I wish somebody could have tracked down who made those puppets.  I have this tiny memory tickling the back of my brain that Mr Rogers may have had an actual Punch and Judy performance once....